# Why is my system crashing?

Tags: hardware

About two months ago, I bought a used HP Compaq DC7900 small form factor tower. I also got a 2TB drive off eBay. I am now on my third drive. Installed Linux  on each drive ( #Manjaro  on the first two, UbuntuMate  on the third ). They would work for a while then slow down and crash. I thought it was the HDDs, but the eBay seller said he put the last one on a long run test and it still acts up. I put an older 80GB drive in it with Windows, elmentaryOS, and crunchbang  installed and that ran with no problem. Could this be a Motherboard issue? Please help.﻿

Comment: what have you set for swappiness? If you have no swappiness or not enough it will sometimes thrash your hard drive and grind to a halt.

Comment: `swapon -s` will give you info

Comment: Someone suggested that I update the BIOS. It had v1.16 and I was able to use grade to v1.26. According to the release notes for the new BIOS, it allowed supported for drives of 2.2TB. I hope that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your SATA connectors are tightly in place, then make sure your hard disk bay is secure.

Comment: When I installed the newest drive, I made sure the SATA cables were tight. In fact, I switched the SATA cable from the HDD for the one on the DVD drive.